# PHP - MySQL- Table doesn't exist

Tags: php, mysql, exists

I have created a table using PHP. When I go to access that table, I get the error -table doesn't exist. I have given all permissions from to the user when creating table. table name is in small letters and if I run the query on local machine it works properly. I think it is a permissions issue but am unable to sort it out.

Comment: what is the error that you get wile connection

Comment: If you think it is a permissions issue, have you tried updating permissions?

Comment: How are you calling the db in the configs?

Comment: I am getting no error during connection or creation of database. I have given full permissions to the user. No i am calling it in the same file.

Comment: Are you sure you are creating a table in your database, not just creating a database.

Comment: Can you post the code where you connect to the DB?

Comment: define("DB_SERVER","localhost");
 define("DB_NAME","vshinde_doctordb");
 define("DB_USER","vshinde_docdb");
 define("DB_PASS","pass123");
 //1. Create Connection
 $connect = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
 
 //2. select database
 $dbConnect = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$connect);
 
 $createQuery = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `01_docmaster` (";
$createQuery .=  "`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,";
$createQuery .=  "`docName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,";
$createQuery .="PRIMARY KEY (`id`))";

$loginQuery = "SELECT * FROM 01_docMaster";
$rsLogin = mysql_query($loginQuery, $connect);

Comment: you have no error handling there

Comment: Have not put in the error handling code. function confirmQuery($recordSet)
 {
  if(!$recordSet)
  {
   die("Error: " . mysql_error());
  }
 }

Comment: Do you get an error then?

Comment: Yes the error is table doesnt exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding some error handling:

```
 $rsLogin = mysql_query($loginQuery, $connect) or die(mysql_error());
```